# How to style a DIV's 2nd UL only

Tags: html, css, selector

I am trying to get http://cssdesk.com/bQTEf

to look like https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhtEh.png

Comment: Your desired image and the "Boxed" text do not agree with each other. What do you want?

Comment: From your edit, I don't understand what you're after. Perhaps make an image and circle the part that should change?

Comment: i am confused no one check the valid markup you forget to close li. are this is valid. are their a reason for write invalid markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how's this? http://cssdesk.com/AezUB

```
#ultest > ul > li > ul:first-child {
    border: 1px solid white;
}
```

also, i dont think the `:first-child` is absolutely necessary.

Comment: Just FYI: The child selector (`>`) is not supported by IE6.